# Get the matched text in RavenDB v4

Tags: ravendb, ravendb4

In RavenDB < 4, you could get the matched word/sentence from a query/search using the FieldHighlightings class:

```
FieldHighlightings highlight = null;
hits = session
  .Advanced
  .DocumentQuery<FAOCRPage>("Standard/Lucene")
  .Statistics(out stats)
  **.Highlight(x => x.OCR, 50, 5, out highlight)**
  .SetHighlighterTags("**", "**")
  .Skip(pageNum*pageSize)
  .Take(pageSize)
  .Search(x => x.OCR, queryStr, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery)
  .ToList();

string[] fragments = highlight.GetFragments(hits[0].Id)
```

And iterate though the highlight variable to get the match text.
I RavenDB v4 this class seems to be removed. How can I get the text the was matched in a query/lucene search and not just the document where it was found in?

I.e. if we have the text "This is a small test, they are going nowhere" and searching using wildcard query for "th*", then I would expect the result "this" and "they" and where they occurred in the text.

Is this not possible anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible in v4.0 but it would be possible with v4.1.

(Planned to be released in a few months).

Comment: Ok, do you know which version of lucene RavenDB are using?